# How to correctly fork a read-stream into 3 compression streams for benchmarking computation?

Tags: node.js, stream

I would like to fork a readStream created from a simple .txt file into 3 compression streams (gzip, brotli and deflate) in order to compute the time it took for each file compression. The current code I have looks something like this:

```
import {createReadStream, createWriteStream} from 'fs';
import zlib from 'zlib';

const main = () => {
    const filename = 'file.txt';
    const fileStream = createReadStream(filename);
    const compressions = {
        createGzip: 'gz',
        createBrotliCompress: 'br',
        createDeflate: 'deflate'
    };
    let {length} = Object.keys(compressions);
    const timings = {};
    for (const [module, ext] of Object.entries(compressions)) {
        timings[module] = Date.now();
        fileStream
            .pipe(zlib[module]())
            .pipe(createWriteStream(`${filename}.${ext}`))
            .on('finish', () => {
                timings[module] = `it took ${Date.now()-timings[module]}ms`;
                if (!--length)
                    console.log(timings);
            });
    }
};

main();
```

However, when I run the script the result it always roughly the same timing for each compression, meaning the 'finish' event must have been fired when the fileStream itself closed, and not for each compression write stream. How do I go about implementing this correctly?

```
{
  createGzip: 'it took 3161ms',
  createBrotliCompress: 'it took 3169ms',
  createDeflate: 'it took 3155ms'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rate limiting a single source to multiple sinks

When piping a stream to multiple sinks, the slowest sink’s execution will throttle the chunk rate of the read stream.

In the OP’s scenario, the read stream will pause reading chunks from “file.txt” when any of the three sinks signal that its write buffer is full (“backpressure”). Consequently, the most efficient sink will have to wait for the slowest sink to process its buffer - and the timings will be more or less the same.

This is fixed by either creating a separate read stream for each sink, or by running the performance tests sequentially.